# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.5.0.0

Tags: c#, azure

On Azure I am getting the following error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at redacted.Encryption.EncryptionManager.get_storageConectionString()
   at redacted..ctor() in<>:line 49

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I updated to azure tools 2.7 and was referencing the 2.5 dll version.

1) Delete the reference to the 2.5 dll in your project (or .csproj file if necessary) and add the reference to the 2.7 System.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime dll.

2)Redeploy.

3)Profit.